# Using NSURLConnection in a loop to download files

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I have a method which gathers a list of needed files, loops through the list and runs a method that uses NSURLConnetion to get the files.

In the loop, the connection to the correct URL is made and a file is downloaded but I'm having problems assigning the correct filename to the file that is returned.  Currently there are 6 files and as a file is returned it is being given the filename of the last file in the list (not the 'current' one). Meaning that the files are overwritten and only the last one is actually saved.

If a condition is satisfied for entries in a loop (comparing timestamps to get the latest file) then the following is run:

```
NSString *tempURL = dict[@"Url"];
fullURL = [@"http://MYURL.com/" stringByAppendingString:tempURL];
[self getFile];
```

So the fullURL is updated and then getFile is called which uses this fullURL to know where to get the file and what to call it.

Then getFile runs which fires off each connection:

```
-(void)getFile {
    NSLog(@"fullURL in getFile = %@", fullURL);  // This shows correct URL
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullURL]];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSString *fileName = [[NSURL URLWithString:fullURL] lastPathComponent]; //This file name is being overwritten before it can be saved
    NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];
    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath];
    [file seekToEndOfFile];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [file seekToEndOfFile];
    [file writeData:data];
}
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
              willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
    return nil;
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [file closeFile];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"error - %@", error);
}
```

I don't understand how getFile is run 6 different times with the fullURL property being updated before it is run each time and then a connection is made to the correct URL and a different file is downloaded but for some reason the last fullURL is being used to created the file name for each one?

Comment: Where did the `connection:didReceiveResponse:currentURL:` method come from?  That isn't a known delegate method, is it?

Comment: Sorry that was me experimenting with passing parameters to the connection, I have removed this from my question.

Comment: So now the code wouldn't compile.. where is `fullURL` declared?

Comment: That was 'work in progress' it compiles without it.  fullURL is declared as an NSString property in getFile.h it has no value until just before [self getFile];

Comment: So you to summarize you are doing an asynchronous download of several files in a loop without waiting for one to finish before starting the next?  Ring any bells?

Comment: Indeed, this wasn't lost on me BUT I did think that each connection could be made and would be treated individually but judging by your response this is not possible and/or the 'right' way?  I guess I could put some check at the end of getFile to not end the method until the connection has been finished?

Comment: It's possible.  You need to decide how many parallel downloads you want simultaneously and you need to hold state for each download. If you want it in a separate background thread then you need to drive the run loop.  Take a look at `testAsyncNetworking` in the following repo, as it might give you some ideas: https://github.com/trojanfoe/RunLoopController

Comment: Thanks again @trojanfoe, I think that has answered my question.  Put up an answer and I'll mark it as such :) I'll take a look at that link now.

Comment: try these links http://stackoverflow.com/a/12895963/3251886, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016202/3251886

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to design a class that tracks the progress of the downloads better and you need to decide how many parallel downloads you want to perform at once.

If you are running that code in a background thread you also need to drive the run loop.

Take a look at `testAsyncNetworking` in the [RunLoopController repo](http://github.com/trojanfoe/RunLoopController), as it might give you some ideas.